# IntegrationFlow HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway reply directly

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-http

I am new to Spring Integration and i am trying to use the HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler and the HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway. The Handler is sending a POST Request and expecting reply. The Gateway is consuming the request. It works fine, BUT the Handler is not getting a reply back. I dont know how to setup my flow, that i can direcly send a reply back and continue my flow.

```
@Bean
public HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler httpOutbound() {
  HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler handler = Http.outboundGateway(restUrl)
        .httpMethod(HttpMethod.POST)
        .messageConverters(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter())
        .mappedRequestHeaders("Content-Type")
        .get();
  handler.setExpectReply(true);
  handler.setOutputChannel(httpResponseChannel());
  return handler;
}

@Bean
public HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway httpRequestGateway() {
  HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway gateway = new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway(true);
  RequestMapping mapping = new RequestMapping();
  mapping.setMethods(HttpMethod.POST);
  mapping.setPathPatterns(httpRequestHandlingPathPattern);
  gateway.setRequestMapping(mapping);
  gateway.setErrorChannel(errorChannel());
  gateway.setReplyChannel(replyChannel());
  gateway.setRequestChannel(requestChannel());
  gateway.setRequestPayloadTypeClass(DocumentConverterInput.class);
  return gateway;
 }

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow documentConverterFlow() {
  return IntegrationFlows
        .from(requestChannel())
        .publishSubscribeChannel(publishSubscribeSpec ->
              publishSubscribeSpec.subscribe(flow -> flow
                          .enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec -> headerEnricherSpec.header("http_statusCode", HttpStatus.OK))
                          .channel(replyChannel())))
        .enrichHeaders(headerEnricherSpec ->
             headerEnricherSpec.headerExpression(Constants.DOCUMENT_CONVERTER_INPUT, "payload"))
        .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(jmsTemplate(connectionFactory)))
        .get();
 }
```

My HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler is successfully posting the request. The HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway is successfully consuming it. At first i had an error "No reply received within timeout", so that i added a publishSubscriberChannel. I don't know if it is the right way, but i cannot find working examples, which show how to reply correctly.

My above code is working, BUT not sending reply back to HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler!

My goal is to receive the request message and directly send back 200 OK. After that i want to continue my integration flow, do some stuff and send the result to queue.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For just `200 OK` response you need to consider to configure an `HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway` with a `expectReply = false`. This way it is going to work as an Inbound Channel Adapter, but having the fact that HTTP is always request-response, it will just do this `setStatusCodeIfNeeded(response, httpEntity);` and your `HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler` on the client side will get an empty, but `OK` resposnse.

Not sure though why your `channel(replyChannel())` doesn't work as expected. It might be the fact that you return a request `palyoad` into a reply message which eventually becomes as a HTTP response, but somehow it fails there, may be during conversion...

**UPDATE**

Here is a simple Spring Boot application demonstrating a *reply-and-process* scenario: https://github.com/artembilan/sandbox/tree/master/http-reply-and-process

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I'll give that a try. You said "For just 200 OK response you need to consider to configure an HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway with a expectReply = false.". What about if i would like to also get other http states, like a states handler? How can i build my flow to achieve that?

Comment: Then it is indeed has to be as a gateway (`new HttpRequestHandlingMessagingGateway()`). Consider to return an empty string as a response. Some simple `.transform()` before `.channel(replyChannel())`

Comment: Can you maybe provide an example please? After that i would except that as a correct answer. Would help me a lot!

Comment: Please, find an UPDATE in my answer. Sorry for delay though. Been busy with release: https://spring.io/blog/2019/10/02/spring-integration-5-2-ga-available

Comment: Thanks for the reply and the example :)

Comment: Ok, this code example is really the same like i did. I made it work. I successfully get a reply. But i thought, that the reply arrives directly when publishSubscribeSpec.subscribe() invokes. But the reply is arriving after the whole flow finished. Is this the normal way or do i missundertand something?

Comment: That’s correct. Because you do everything in the same thread. To return control to the gateway in the beginning waiting for reply, we indeed need to finish all the work in that thread. To change behavior, you can use an `executor` for that publish-subscribe making subscribers to work in the separate threads and in most cases in parallel

Comment: I understand, thank you very much! This helped a lot!